# Функция по удалению среза из байт-кода, удаляет лишь последний срез

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytearray

Требуется удалить часть байт кода.

Функция `remove_str()` принимает имя файла и блок byte данных. `self.offset_arr` - это массив срезов вида `i[1] = [50, 100]`, они передаются с помощью цикла `for` функции `remove_bytes()`.

По идее функция должна удалять срез из байт кода и перезаписывать текущий файл. Но вместо этого удаляет, лишь, последний срез. Как сделать так, чтобы функция удалила все срезы из байт-кода и возвратила чистый файл.

```
def remove_bytes(self,fname,block):
    with open(fname,"wb") as f:
        s = bytearray()
        arr = self.reverse_offset_arr()
        print(arr)
        s.extend(block[0:self.offset_arr[0][0]])
        for i in range((len(arr)-2)):   
            s.extend(block[arr[i]:arr[i+1]])
        s.extend(block[self.offset_arr[(len(self.offset_arr)-1)][0]:])
        f.write(s)

def remove_str(self,fname,block):
    self.remove_bytes(fname,block)        
    print("Clean file is finished")
    

def reverse_offset_arr(self):
    result = []
    result2 = []
    for i in self.offset_arr:
        for j in range(2):
            result.append(i[j])

    for i in range(len(result)):
        if(i<(len(result)-2)):
            result2.append(result[i+1])
    return result2
```

Код был изменен, теперь он удаляет лишь первый срез. В чем ошибка?

Прикрепляю данные массивов:

`self.offset_arr`:

```
(416402, 416426)
(416661, 416695)
(417508, 417571)
(418264, 418324)
(418381, 418446)
(418525, 418601)
(419785, 419786)
```

`reverse_offset_arr`:

```
[416426, 416661, 416695, 417508, 417571, 418264, 418324, 418381, 418446, 418525, 418601, 419785]
```

Comment: Не нужно менять вопрос после того, как вам уже дали ответ, это автоматически делает ответ неправильным. Если возник новый вопрос - задавайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы в коде следующие:

1. При открытии файла в режиме `"wb"` файл каждый раз перезаписывается при открытии.
2. В цикле у вас каждый раз заново создается кусок данных с вырезанным одним срезом (каждый раз разным). Т.е. если решить первую проблему, то у вас в файл N раз будет записан один и тот же блок данных с вырезанным куском каждый раз в разных местах.

Правильный алгоритм примерно такой:

1. берем список срезов, сортируем по возрастанию начала диапазона
2. сливаем пересекающиеся диапазоны
3. превращаем список вырезаемых срезов в список оставляемых ("инвертируем" диапазоны)
4. один раз открываем файл, в цикле проходим по списку оставляемых срезов, вырезаем куски из блока данных, сразу записываем в файл (без промежуточного сложения срезов в bytearray)

Answer (score 0):

Функция по удалению среза из байт-кода remove_bytes()

```
def remove_bytes(self,fname,block):
    with open(fname,"wb") as f:
        i = 0;
        s = bytearray()
        arr = self.reverse_offset_arr()
        print(arr)
        s.extend(block[0:self.offset_arr[0][0]])
        while(i<(len(arr)-1)):   
            s.extend(block[arr[i]:arr[i+1]])
            print(i)
            i += 2

        s.extend(block[self.offset_arr[(len(self.offset_arr)-1)][0]:])
        f.write(s)

def remove_str(self,fname,block):
    self.remove_bytes(fname,block)        
    print("Clean file is finished")


def reverse_offset_arr(self):
    result = []
    result2 = []
    for i in self.offset_arr:
        for j in range(2):
            result.append(i[j])

    for i in range(len(result)):
        if(i<(len(result)-2)):
            result2.append(result[i+1])
    return result2
```